Word addin - Office js Api - ReadOnly document
HI Is it possible via the Office JS API to manipulate the Word document or individual paragraphs so as to make them read-only? To be clear, I would like to do this: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/allow-changes-to-parts-of-a-protected-document-187ed01c-8795-43e1-9fd0-c9fca419dadf Thanks in advance

What have you tried so far? Post code you tried it with and we can help debug.

At present, you can’t call the JS API to protect a Word document using that feature. If you’d like to see this feature in the API, post or upvote on the Microsoft 365 Developer Platform Ideas Forum.
A couple of options that may work for you:
a. Wrap the paragraph with a content control (see Paragraph.insertContentControl) then set the ContentControl.cannotEdit property to true.
b. Manipulate the document’s OOXML (see Understand when and how to use Office Open XML in your Word add-in). This option may require more trial and error if you’re not already familiar with OOXML.

Thank you
Solution number one might work for me
I'm trying to block content from book1 to book2
I do it like this
            var range = firstBookmarkRange.expandTo(secondBookmarkRange);
            await context.sync();
            range.load({ $all: true });
            await context.sync();                  
            var cc = range.insertContentControl();
            cc.cannotEdit = true;
            await context.sync();

doing this blocks only the first paragraph starting from the bookmark, the following range does not
How can I do it?

Even if I do this by selecting multiple lines, the contentcontrols is inserted only on the first line from where I selected to the bottom of the same
The other lines are ignored
            const range = context.document.getSelection();
            const wordContentControl = range.insertContentControl();
            wordContentControl.cannotEdit = true;
            await context.sync()


I've seen now that if I block an entire paragraph with content control, when I exit content control it makes me write on the same line, this isn't good for me

Hi, Rick
I managed to block the section of the document with the content control
It works and I like it
The problem is that if I exit the first or last blocked content control I can write to the beginning of the document or to the end
Do you think there's a way for me not to leave content control? So as not to write text at the beginning or end of the document
